# TCP Echo Server Using thread command line not showing

Tags: c++, c, server, tcp

In my project wants  when client side write like LIST the server side will directory list documents  and after when I write like  GET filename.txt  but in the server side not shows me any thing ı think is stop how can I solve this problem  my project describer in photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lFUK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3k1C.png)

source  code is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



#include <dirent.h> 

/* Definations */
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024
#define PORT 1888

void PANIC(char* msg);
#define PANIC(msg)  { perror(msg); exit(-1); }

 
 
bool StartsWith(const char *a, const char *b)
{
   if(strncmp(a, b, strlen(b)) == 0) return 1;
   return 0;
}
 

void* Child(void* arg)
{   char line[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int bytes_read;
     
    int client = *(int *)arg;


    
    
 send(client,"Welcome to Vepa Server\n",strlen("Welcome to Vepa Server\n"),0);
    do
    {
           

         bytes_read = recv(client, line, sizeof(line), 0);
          
     
       
        if (bytes_read > 0) {

        printf("%s",line);  

 
 // list command in here
       if (strcmp(line,"LIST\n") ==0)
        {
           while(1)
           {
               DIR *d;
               struct dirent *dir;
               d = opendir(".");
              if (d) {
               while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
              
                 send(client,dir->d_name,strlen(dir->d_name),0);
                 send(client,"\n",strlen("\n"),0);

                
             }
             closedir(d);
       }
       return(0);

           }
        }

        if (StartsWith(line,"GET") == 1)
        {
             printf(line);
        }
        
 
        
      
        
 

     if ( (bytes_read=send(client, line, bytes_read, 0)) < 0 ) {
                        printf("Send failed\n");
                        break;
                }
        } else if (bytes_read == 0 ) {
                printf("Connection closed by client\n");
                break;
        } else {
                printf("Connection has problem\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (bytes_read > 0);
    close(client);
    return arg;
}

 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    
   
     int sd,opt,optval;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    unsigned short port=0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'p':
                port=atoi(optarg);
                break;
        }
    }


    if ( (sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
        PANIC("Socket");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if ( port > 0 )
                addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    else
                addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   // set SO_REUSEADDR on a socket to true (1):
   optval = 1;
   setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);


    if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
        PANIC("Bind");
    if ( listen(sd, SOMAXCONN) != 0 )
        PANIC("Listen");

    printf("System ready on port %d\n",ntohs(addr.sin_port));

 
    while (1)
    {
        int client, addr_size = sizeof(addr);
        pthread_t child;

        client = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_size);
      
        
         
        printf("Connected: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
         
       
        
          

        if ( pthread_create(&child, NULL, Child, &client) != 0 )
            perror("Thread creation");
        else
            pthread_detach(child);  /* disassociate from parent */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no detailed error description, i.e. all what you basically say is that it does not work. I recommend that you augment your code with debug output, so that you can verify your expectations at the various places in your code and thus narrow down where the program execution does not match your expectations.

Comment: I want to integrate the description in the first picture into these codes, but I don't know how and where to start

Comment: the posted code is C, not C++.  Please correct the list of 'tags'

Comment: regarding: `while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'p':
                port=atoi(optarg);
                break;
        }
    }`  this is allowing for multiple instances of a `-p` command line parameter.  Probably not what you want

Comment: regarding: `unsigned short port=0;`   0 is not a valid port number.  Infact, port numbers 0...1024 are 'reserved' for special use cases and (generally) should not be used in user code.  suggest the initial value for `port` be above 1024.  Also the 'firewall' has to allow the selected port to transfer data

Comment: The posted code contains a (buggy) 'server' code, and is missing the matching 'client' code

Comment: Please do not post links to images,  rather, copy/paste the text as part of the question

Comment: regarding: `bytes_read = recv(client, line, sizeof(line), 0);
          
     
       
        if (bytes_read > 0) {

        printf("%s",line);`   the function: `recv()` does not NUL terminate the input data, so the code must do it.  via: `line[  bytes_read ] = '\0';` this: `bytes_read = recv(client, line, sizeof(line), 0);`  does not allow room to add the NUL terminator so suggest: `sizeof(line)` be: `sizeof(line) -1`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question contains links to images rather than having the text be part of the question

Comment: regarding: *I want to integrate the description in the first picture into these codes,*  one way: highlite the text, copy the highlited text, edit the question, paste the text into the question

Comment: regarding: `send(client,"Welcome to Vepa Server\n",strlen("Welcome to Vepa Server\n"),0);`   Always check the returned value to assure the `send()` was successful (or not)

Comment: regarding: `int bytes_read;` and `bytes_read = recv(client, line, sizeof(line), 0);`   the function: `recv()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: strongly suggest: when listing directory/file names that the file type be checked so sub-directories, links, entries with names like; `.` and `..` do not be passed to the client